# Ajax POST is hanging

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, cgi

I have a webform which is just an easy bunch of textareas writing data via CGI to a SQL database. This works fine.

My problem is that, in addition to the `<input type='submit'/>` that I have to submit the form I also want it be submitted if the user navigates away from the page - to achieve this I have the following jQuery:

```
    <script>
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){{
            $.ajax({{
                type:'POST',
                url:'../save_teacher_actions_no_redirect.py',
                data:'group={group}&AP={AP}&year=14/15&' + $('#ta_form').serialize(),
                success:function(){{}}
                }});
        }});
    </script>
```

In Chrome dev tools for instance I can see that the POST to 'save_teacher_actions_no_redirect.py' happens, as does the GET to the page that I'm requesting to ensure that this event triggers on navigation, however neither request seems to complete, and the page is just left hanging with the status in dev tools as `(pending)`

The .py file the ajax POST is calling works fine as far as I can see - logging throws no errors or anything and there's definitely no loops it's getting trapped in or anything of that kind, so I am at a loss as to why it would hang.

```
#!C:\Python34\python.exe
import datetime
import pymssql
import cgi
import os
from connection_data import NationalAverages
myDB = NationalAverages()
from pm_authenticate import authenticate_user_against_group

#logging
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler=logging.FileHandler('error_log.log')
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Connection details for the database       
cursor = myDB.connect_to_db()
conn = myDB.conn

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def right(string):
    return string[len(string)-1]

def default_value(value):
    if value is None:
        return ' '
    else:
        return value

def left(string):
    return string[0:3]

def save_data(form):
    group = form.getfirst("group", "7bg/IL4")
    AP = form.getfirst("AP", "AP2")
    academic_year = form.getfirst("year", "14/15")
    list_of_ids = []

    # get ids of the rows on page
    for key in form.keys():
        if ((left(key) == 'ta_' or left(key) == 'da_') and right(key).isnumeric()):
            if int(right(key)) in list_of_ids:
                continue
            else:
                list_of_ids.append(int(right(key)))
        else:
            continue

    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Teacher_Actions WHERE Academic_Year = %s AND group_code = %s AND AP = %s', (academic_year, group, AP))
    existing_ids = cursor.fetchall()

    for id in existing_ids:
        if id in list_of_ids:
            continue
        else:
            cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Teacher_Actions WHERE ID = %d AND Academic_Year = %s AND group_code = %s AND AP = %s', (id, academic_year, group, AP))
            conn.commit()


    for id in list_of_ids:      

        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Teacher_Actions WHERE ID = %d AND Academic_Year = %s AND AP= %s AND group_code =%s', (id, academic_year, AP, group))
        existing_data = cursor.fetchone()
        if not existing_data:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Teacher_Actions VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (id, academic_year, group, AP, form.getvalue('ta_students_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_gaps_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_action_when_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_success_point_' + str(id))))
            conn.commit()
        else:
            cursor.execute('UPDATE Teacher_Actions SET Students = %s, Gaps = %s, Action_When = %s, Success_Point = %s WHERE ID = %d AND Academic_Year = %s AND Group_Code = %s AND AP = %s', (form.getvalue('ta_students_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_gaps_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_action_when_' + str(id)), form.getvalue('ta_success_point_' + str(id)), id, academic_year, group, AP))
            conn.commit()

try:
    save_data(form)
except:
    logger.exception(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Advice please!

Comment: Why do you have two braces around both the ajax call and the beforeunload function?

Comment: HTML page is generated by a CGI call which requires double bracing to escape them - single braces are interpreted as being variables to be filled in.

Comment: You say the request hangs which would mean there is a problem on the server end. Yet, you only post your client side code.

Comment: @jsfan - added the .py file's code. I am kind of working on the assumption it's not that file as there's an almost identical file working fine elsewhere but I would be happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: Have you tried to find out if your server side script finishes? In that case, it could be your web server not closing the connection correctly and maybe even buffering the output forever.

Comment: @jsfan -  as far as I can tell it's never even called. If, say, I stick a couple lines at the start of that file telling it to write "test" to a file, that doesn't work. So I don't think it's actually getting as far as the .py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. In essence it's because the file I was POSTing to was a .py not a .cgi...my inexperience shines brightly once more.